# Prove that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is uniformly continuous in $[1, +∞)$ if $f$ is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f(x)$ be a Lipschitz function on $[1, +∞)$, i.e. there exists a
>   positive constant $C$ such that $$|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ C|x − y|, ∀x, y ∈ [1, +∞).$$
>
> Prove that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is uniformly continuous in $[1,+\infty)$.

I know that a  Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous. What I did so far is:

let $g(x)  = \frac{f(x)}{x}$. Then I assumed $g(x)$ is Lipschitz. (Is the assumption wrong?) 
Then  $|g(x)-g(y)| \le K|x-y|$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition.

Therefore $|\frac{yf(x)-xf(y)}{xy}| \le K|x-y|$.

How to continue from here?

Comment: This reminds me of Cauchy's mean value theorem, except that here $f$ is not differentiable. You might want to check out how the theorem is proved.

Comment: @GNUEmacs I did not learn this theorem in class. But I will still check the theorem though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is indeed Lipschitz: First of all, from 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le C|x-y|$$
putting $y=1$ gives
$$\tag{1} |f(x)| = |f(x) - f(1)+ f(1)|\le C|x-1| + |f(1)|.$$
Now using $(1)$ and $x, y\ge 1$,

$$\begin{split}
|g(x) - g(y)| &= \left| \frac{f(x)}{x} - \frac{f(y)}{y}\right| \\
&=  \left| \frac{f(x)}{x} - \frac{f(y)}{x} + \frac{f(y)}{x} - \frac{f(y)}{y}\right| \\
&\le \left| \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x}\right| + |f(y)| \left|\frac 1x - \frac 1y\right| \\
&\le |f(x) - f(y)| + |f(y)| \left|\frac{x-y}{xy} \right| \\
&\le C|x-y| + \frac{C|y-1| + |f(1)|}{|xy|} |x-y| \\
&\le C|x-y| + \left( C + |f(1)\right) |x-y| \\
&= K|x-y|,
\end{split}$$

where $K = 2C + |f(1)|$. Thus $g$ is also Lipschitz and so is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @johmma why do we have to check for y=1?

Comment: We need $(1)$ so that $f$ has at most "linear growth". You could use $y=2$ or $3$ instead. Then you get $|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(2)+ f(2)|\le |f(x) - f(2)| + |f(2)|$. $1$ is not important. Very important is the linear growth estimates of $f$ (equation (1)). This is used in the last inequlity @Ramos

Comment: In your second to last inequality, where did the $|y-1|$ disappear to?

Comment: $\frac{C|y-1|}{|xy|}\le \frac{C|y|}{|x||y|} \le C$ @user46944

Comment: neat and clean answer :)

Answer (score 3):

**Below is an incomplete proof that might not even be the right way to go**.

But I'm posting it anyway (at least temporarily) so that you see one way to think about/work through these problems in general.  The problem at the end of this proof is that $|f(y)|$ is not necessarily bounded by a constant, so we were unable to find a Lipschitz constant.

$\left | \dfrac{f(x)}{x} - \dfrac{f(y)}{y}  \right | $

$= \left | \dfrac{yf(x) - x f(y)}{xy}  \right |$

$ = \left | \dfrac{yf(x) - yf(y) + yf(y)- x f(y)}{xy}  \right |$

$ \leq \left | \dfrac{yf(x) - yf(y)}{xy}  \right | + \left | \dfrac{yf(y)- x f(y)}{xy}  \right |$

$= \left | \dfrac{f(x) - f(y)}{x}  \right | + |f(y)|\left | \dfrac{y- x }{xy}  \right |$

$\leq C\left | \dfrac{x - y}{x}  \right | + |f(y)|\left | \dfrac{y- x }{xy}  \right |$

$\leq \left (C + \dfrac{|f(y)|}{|y|} \right ) \left | \dfrac{x - y}{x}   \right |$

$\leq \left (C + \dfrac{|f(y)|}{|1|} \right ) \left | \dfrac{x - y}{1}   \right |$ (since $x, y \in [1, \infty)$)

$= (C + |f(y)| )  \cdot |x - y|$