# Proving uniform continuity of $\frac{f(x)}{x^{\alpha}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

> Suppose $A>0$,and let $f$ be  function which is Lipschitz continuous in $[A,\infty)$. Prove that for all $\alpha \geq 1$, the function $\frac{f(x)}{x^{\alpha}}$ is uniformly continuous in $[A,\infty)$.

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

My try. When $\alpha=1$,then from the Lipschitz condition, we can get that $|f(x)|\leq |f(A)|+L|x-A|$. From this, we can claim there exists $L′$>0, such that $\frac{|f(x)|}{x} \leq L'$ and at last we get $$|\frac{f(y)}{y}-\frac{f(x)}{x}|\leq \frac {|f(y)-f(x)|}{y}+\frac{|x-y|}{y}\frac{|f(y)}{x}\leq L''|y-x|.$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: when $\alpha=1$,then from the Lipschitz condition ,we can get that$\|f(x)\|\leq \|f(x)\|+L\|x-A\|$;From this, we can claim there exists $L'>0$,such that $\frac{\|f(x)\|}{x} \leq L'$

Comment: when $\alpha=1$,then from the Lipschitz condition ,we can get that$\|f(x)\|\leq \|f(x)\|+L\|x-A\|$;From this, we can claim there exists $L'>0$,such that $\frac{\|f(x)\|}{x} \leq L'$,at last we can get $\|\frac{f(y)}{y}-\frac{f(x)}{x}\|\leq \frac {|f(y)-f(x)|}{y}+\frac{|x-y|}{y}\frac{|f(y)}{x}\leq L''|y-x|$

Answer (score 1):

As regards the case $\alpha=1$, you are on the right track. See also [Prove that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is uniformly continuous in $[1, +∞)$ if $f$ is Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546901/prove-that-fracfxx-is-uniformly-continuous-in-1-%E2%88%9E-if-f-is-lipsc)

For $\alpha>1$, since $f(x)/x$ is bounded, it follows that
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^{\alpha}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)/x}{x^{\alpha-1}}=0.$$ 
Then use [Prove that $f$ is uniform continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290563/prove-that-f-is-uniform-continuous)

Comment: Is the conculsion of link right with the counterexample $sin(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: Yes. Here $f$ is continuous on $[A,+\infty)$ (closed set).

Comment: but how to explain the counterexample $sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: This is not a counterexample...

Comment: Thank you ,I am sorry for ingoring the fact that $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not uniformly continuously in open set$(A,\infty)$

Comment: Fine. I included your try under your question. It's better to show what you did. Welcome to MSE and please take a tour before asking new questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thanks pretty much

Answer (score 1):

Let $0 < A  \le x_1 < x_2$.  Then $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous if and only if
$$
\dfrac{|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|}{|x_1-x_2|} \le K
$$ 
for some constant $K$.  Now consider
$$
\dfrac{|f(x_1)/x_1^\alpha-f(x_2)/x_2^\alpha|}{|x_1-x_2|} 
$$ 
Since $\alpha \ge 1$, we may write
$$
\dfrac{|f(x_1)/x_1^\alpha-f(x_2)/x_2^\alpha|}{|x_1-x_2|} < \dfrac{|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|/A^\alpha}{|x_1-x_2|} 
$$
Hence if $g(x)=f(x)/x^\alpha$, then 
$$
\dfrac{|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|}{|x_1-x_2|} \le KA^\alpha
$$
So $g(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous, and every such function is uniformly continuous.